# Adding NSMutableDictionary's in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm scanning an NSMutableArray of dictionary's and request to a WebService a info from each data.

The problem is after get the data, i need to update 2 keys of the same array of dictionary's and when i added an object, the array continues empty.

What is wrong?!

PS: using ARC

```
NSMutableArray* arrayOfDicts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                 [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"2013",@"year",
                   @"a1beb511-7fe1-434b-ab87-a0d02fb47713",@"yearTB",
                   @"",@"receita_arrecadada",
                   @"",@"receita_prevista_atualizada",
                 nil],
                 [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  @"2012",@"year",
                  @"5d20f841-d790-4671-ae26-505c9a8c7f76",@"yearTB",
                  @"",@"receita_arrecadada",
                  @"",@"receita_prevista_atualizada",
                 nil],
               nil];

__block NSMutableArray* arrayTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];;
__block NSMutableDictionary* dicTemp;

for(dicTemp in arrayOfDicts){

    NSString* year = [dicTemp objectForKey:@"year"];
    NSString* yearTB = [dicTemp objectForKey:@"yearTB"];
    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [RequestFacade getReceiptsTotalInYear:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yearTB] andCompletion:^(Receipt *receipt) {

        //NSLog(@"%@",receipt.receita_arrecadada); // Print the correct actual value

        [newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:dicTemp];

        [newDict setObject:year forKey:@"year"];
        [newDict setObject:yearTB forKey:@"yearTB"];
        [newDict setObject:receipt.receita_arrecadada forKey:@"receita_arrecadada"];
        [newDict setObject:receipt.receita_atualizada forKey:@"receita_atualizada"];

        [arrayTemp addObject:newDict];
        NSLog(@"%@", arrayTemp); // shows me the array of dicts

        // until here, its ok!
    }]; 
}
NSLog(@"%@", arrayTemp); // shows me an empty array...F*CK!
```

Comment: First initialise the arrayOfDict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise your `arrayOfDict`.

```
NSMutableArray * arrayOfDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The array is empty because you are not initialising it. write this above line at the top and then add

```
[arrayOfDict arrayWithObjects: <UR ITEMS>];
```

Hope it works..!! Happy Coding

Comment: This var is an example of the real code. The Array its already initializated. The problem is when i add to the new array.

Comment: I think your array is released after the execution of for loop but dont know the reason, try to debug it. And also try to make the newArray as a class property. @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * newArray; and initialise this array using self.newArray;